# postgresql PBES2 SecretKeyFactory not available

Tags: postgresql, openssl

I have a local postgres instance that is created with `ssl`

the `openssl` configuration is created as:

```
CERT_LOC=certs
PSQL_CONF_LOC=resources/psql.conf
ENCRYPT_PASSWD=resources/psql_ssl_pwd

rm certs/*

echo "generating postgresql.key"
openssl genpkey -quiet -algorithm rsa -out $CERT_LOC/postgresql.key -outform pem  # -aes256
echo "generating postgresql.cert"
# https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-req.html
openssl req -new -key $CERT_LOC/postgresql.key -days 365 -out $CERT_LOC/postgresql.cert -x509 -config $PSQL_CONF_LOC
echo "generating postgresql.pk8"
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in $CERT_LOC/postgresql.key -outform DER -out $CERT_LOC/postgresql.pk8 -v2 aes256 -passout file:$ENCRYPT_PASSWD  # -nocrypt
echo "all 3 done"
```

where `PSQL_CONF` is:

```
[ req ]
default_bits                    = 2048
default_md                      = sha256
prompt                          = no
encrypt_key                     = yes
distinguished_name              = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = AA
stateOrProvinceName             = AAAAA
localityName                    = AAAAA
organizationName                = AAAAAAAAAA
commonName                      = some.dns.common.name.local
```

These are the `postgresql.conf` that I've edited:

```
## SSL CONFIG
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = '/opt/postgresql/root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = '/opt/postgresql/tls.crt'
ssl_key_file = '/opt/postgresql/tls.key'
ssl_passphrase_command = 'SOMEPASSWORDISET'
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
```

These are the `pg_hba.conf` config:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256     # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256     # IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256     # IPv6 local connections:
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
#host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
#host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
hostssl all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256 clientcert=verify-ca      # IPv4 remote connections for authenticated users
hostssl all             all             ::/0                    scram-sha-256 clientcert=verify-ca      # IPv6 remote connections for authenticated users
```

**what i've tried**

The first test I did was right at the start `openssl` section, where on generating the `pk8` key, i set `nocrypt` flag. Applied all the config, and I was able to get it to load up, and connect to postgres (with intelilj) with the certs.

**where the error came about**

however, in the next test, in `openssl` section, i entered `-passout pass:SOMETEXTpassword` and go through the process, I"m hit with the following error when I try to use intellij to connect.

```
DBMS: PostgreSQL (ver. 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1))  Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=exact Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (ver. 42.5.0, JDBC4.2)

java.io.IOException: JCE error: PBES2 SecretKeyFactory not available.
```

What should I do to solve this?